# bootstrap: change class of tr in a table when radio button selected

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap. How could I change the class of the tr (with class="active" for example) when the radio button inside the tr is selected ?

```
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>Description A</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="items" value="A"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>Description B</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="items" value="B"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>C</td>
          <td>Description C</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="items" value="C"></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(":radio[name=items]").change(function() {
    $(".table tr.active").removeClass("active"); //remove previous active class
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("active"); //add active to radio selected tr
});
```

Comment: Nice, that works. How to target the radio buttons without specifying the name of the radio ("items") but just every radio button that are in a table?

Comment: @YAmikep -- Just use `table :radio` for that - so `$("table :radio")`

Comment: ok thanks, i tried with a specific class as well: $(".radio-table-row")  Any impact on using one over the other?

Comment: @YAmikep -- shouldnt be.

Comment: I'm trying to make the row clickable as well. When it is clicked, I'd like the same behavior than when the radio button is clicked, i.e. add/remove the active class and the radio button is checked. I tried that but does not work: ``$('.table > tr').click(function() {
        $(".table tr.active").removeClass("active"); //remove previous active class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //add active to radio selected tr
    });``